# Ignite near cache - Can the same distributed cache be configured to be a near cache in one ignite client & a regular cache in another ignite client?

Tags: ignite, gridgain

Folks,

Does anyone know the behavior for the below two items on Ignite Near Cache,

1. Can the same distributed cache on the ignite grid be configured to be a near cache in one ignite client & a regular cache in another ignite client at the same time?. Hopefully this can be done.
2. Does near caches work when using SQL queries (we use Spring Data abstraction) or does it work only with JCache based key-value access.

Thanks
lmk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think you should be able to only start Near Cache on a subset of clients. Have you tried that.
2. No, SQL map phase will not happen on clients, it will happen on primary server node(s).

Comment: Thanks @alamar, for point one, not yet..will try & update if it doesn't work; for point two, i thought so aswell & that its not straight forward since the server & client nodes might need to have some additional logic in place to effect this, but just wanted to confirm the behavior..thanks for that...do u know if there is a plan to support this?..if so i had like to vote for that.

Comment: I don't think that any additional logic is needed.

Comment: i gather you mean that its impossible to support this for SQL queries, is it?

Comment: I was referring to 1.

Comment: Cool..yeah for point 1 i understand no additional logic is needed, just that i need to try configuring an existing cache on one client node only as near cache & leave it as regular on others & test if it works fine as expected..btw one more question this also means one needs to configure the heap keeping in mind the on-heap caching & set the near cache eviction policy aswell...rite?

Comment: You can have near cache, on heap cache, or both.

Comment: let me understand this right, the documentation for [ignite 2.5](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.5/docs/near-caches) does not mention that near cache is stored on-heap. However the current [ignite 2.7](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.7/docs/near-caches) does mention this explicitly, so i thought near caches are stored on heap (figured doc may be updated just now). Is my understanding incorrect for ignite 2.5? We are currently on ignite 2.5.

Comment: OK, I guess that you are right here. Both are stored on heap.

Comment: Thanks @alamar, that means we need to keep the heap sizing in mind along with the eviction policy..will do..thank again.